# SqlDataReader doesn't read when column empty

Tags: c#, sql-server, types, datareader

I have a problem with the following code:

```
public void checkTypes(String sqlTable, String sqlColumn)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new       SqlConnection(conStr.Text))
    {
        String query = "SELECT " + sqlColumn + " FROM " + sqlTable;

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (read.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < read.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                Type dataType = read.GetFieldType(i);

                if (dataType == typeof(int))
                {
                    // Do for integers (INT, SMALLINT, BIGINT)
                    typeOf = "Integer";
                    read.Close();
                    connection.Close();
                    return;
                }
                else if (dataType == typeof(double))
                {
                     //and so on...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now... I just want to check the types of my columns but the problem is that when the table gets created it has no entries and then the while loop does not get entered at all. How can I modify this slightly without writing completely new code? I don't want to insert pseudo values. Thank you! Hope someone can help me.

EDIT:

Ok so I explain a little bit more:
The user can enter column names in different textboxes. Now I want to take the column name from each box and check if the datatype matches the datatype the column should have.

Comment: what database are you using ? if SqlServer you can get this info from system table INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS; other db's probably have similar system tables you can use

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Discounting the remaining `else..if` statements, as soon as you find an `int`, you return from the method.
You can't do this with an `SqlDataReader`, as the `FieldCount` property will return `-1` if you don't have a current row.  If you want to deal with data types only, you could query the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Akhil beat me to it but I would expand it to

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'tableName' AND column_name = 'columnName'
```

since you have the column names and the table name already

Comment: Yes I have the tablename and the column names already. How do I use this within my construct? Or better said. Where to put the connection string in and the other information?

Comment: you would run this query before you run your select query. You can put it within your using statement. You would have to store the results someplace and refer to them when the time comes.

Comment: No problem. glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

considering that you just have to check the datatypes of columns,if you want to get the column datatype in SQL database alone,you could use the query

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'yourTableName'
```

hope this helps.But this wont help in retrieving data and column datatype simultaneously.

Comment: I have to check if the column names have the right data type.

Comment: ya if you don't bother about  data in that column just use the above way.